# Call page load event on browser's back button press

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've written a function on page_load event of aspx page. Problem i'm facing is the function doesn't get call when browser's back button is pressed, or you can say page_load event is not fired. I want to call this function whenever user press browser's back button.
I've tried

```
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

but it didn't worked.
Please help, thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the function is not called? have you placed a breakpoint in the page_load to verify this? normally it should be called.

Comment: This should work. Are you sure the page isn't ALREADY cached and you simply need to clear your browser cache?

Comment: Ya I used break point to verify, but no effect. Its not working

Comment: Ya @Beakie i tried multiple times, also i build my solution to check, but i didn't worked

Comment: Is the no cache header being set in the HTML page?

Comment: Ya i used     <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">  in my aspx page. Is it correct?

Comment: Also include max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store

<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />

Comment: It should be noted though that browsers don't need to acknowledge meta tags.

Comment: I tried the code, but it didn't worked. I'm using IE 9.

Comment: Have you confirmed that it is being cached? Have you timestamped the page or something similar?

Comment: Did you breakpoint the entry point to the method, or where your code is being called?

Comment: Output the current time...

Comment: Ya I've checked the same, its not been cached.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser? It IS possible to override caching options in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Set postback=true to controls.
After fetching the data, clear the controls text. then proceed to next page.
When user clicks "Back" button, the controls will be clear.